# How to do device pairing in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I want to implement device pairing functionality in my App.So I can paired(connect) device .
Is there any solution available in codename one for pairing device?

Comment: What method do you want to use for pairing? what device are you pairing with? And besides, your question is too broad.

Comment: @Diamond is correct. I'm guessing you mean bluetooth pairing https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone